# Improving performance of hive jdbc

Tags: performance, hadoop, jdbc, hive, hortonworks-data-platform

Does aynyone know how to increase performance for HIVE JDBC connection.

Detailed problem:

When I query hive from Hive CLI, I get a response within 7 sec but from HIVE JDBC connection I get a response after 14 sec. I was wondering if there is any way (configuration changes) with which I can improve performance for query through JDBC connection.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be really helpful to get additional information like versions, current configuration (if any), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Using Connection pooling helped me increase hive JDBC performance.
As in hive there are many transformations happening while we query so using existing connection objects from connection pool instead of opening a new connection and closing for each request was quite helpful.

Please let me know if any one else if facing same issue will post a detailed answer.

Comment: Can you add more details to your answer for e.g., if you have done any configuration or code changes.

Comment: @techprat i have a big hive query with joins and grouping and it is taking an hour to run it, anyway to improve performance using hive jdbc

Comment: @Ankita: Is it like from Hive CLI the queries are faster and slow thru jdbc ?

Comment: Yes, jdbc definitely takes couple of minutes more than hive CLI

Comment: Set fetchsize parameter to a higher number if the resultSet is huge. Default fetchSize=1000. For one of my queries I had put fetchSize=1000000 and saw considerable performance gains.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the below options.

1. If your query has joins then try setting the **hive.auto.convert.join** to **true**.
2. Try changing the configuration of **Java Heap Size and Garbage Collection** reference [**Link**](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/admin_hive_tuning.html#id_umf_bmk_nw)
3. Change the execution engine to Tez using **set hive.execution.engine=tez**
   To check currently set engine use **hive.execution.engine**.

Other Hive performance configuration tips can be found in the [**Link**](https://streever.atlassian.net/wiki/display/HADOOP/Hive+Performance+Tips)

Please let me know the results.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have already applied these configuration while using Hive CLI. My concern is to speed up hive queries through Hive JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

To improve the performance of jdbc connection 
Use the standard jdbc performance improvement features -,connection pooling , prepared statement pooling (starting with jdbc 3.0)                                                            performance improvement of hive cli can be done by changing these configuration parameters

```
-- enable cost based optimizer
set hive.cbo.enable=true;
set hive.compute.query.using.stats=true;
set hive.stats.fetch.column.stats=true;
set hive.stats.fetch.partition.stats=true;

--collects statistics
analyze table <TABLENAME> compute statistics for columns;

--enable vectorization of queries.
set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled = true;
set hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled = true;
```

Hope thos helps

Comment: See my comment for ans above :)

Answer (score 0):

If your database is Oracle you can try the [Oracle Table Access for Hadoop and Spark (OTA4H)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E65728_01/doc.43/e65665/GUID-C2A509A4-34CB-4B58-AC55-6CCCE51163A8.htm#BIGUG76783) which can also be used from Hive QL. OTA4H will optimize the JDBC queries to retrieve the data from Oracle using splitters in order to get the best performance. You can join Hive tables with external tables inside Oracle directly in your hive queries.